# typescript generic callable argument

Tags: typescript, express

I would like to know how to specify the type for a generic argument that is callable, `controller` in the example below.

```js
//utils/adapters.ts

import express from 'express'

export const postHandler = <ControllerT>(controller: ControllerT) => (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  controller(req.body).then((payload: ReturnType<ControllerT>) => {
    res.status(200).json(payload)
  })
}
```

VSCode shows the dreaded red squiggly on the `controller` variable when used in the expression `controller(req.body)` with this message:

> This expression is not callable. Type 'unknown' has no call signatures.

Runnning `tsc` I see the same error as in VS Code.

I have many places I want to apply the pattern above in my Express.js application, for example:

```js
// routes/search.ts
import express from 'express'
import { postHandler } from '../utils/adapters'

import {
  searchFoo,
  searchBar,
} from '../controllers/search'

const router = express.Router()
router.post('/foo', postHandler(searchFoo))
router.post('/bar', postHandler(searchBar))

export default router
```

**UPDATE:**
I was asked to add more context about the usage. I dont think it should be the focus because the idea is that the types below are inferred in the above usage.

```js
// controllers/search.ts
interface SearchFooParams {
  phrase: string
}

interface Foo {
  id: string
  name: string
}

interface SearchFooResponse {
  query: SearchFooParams["phrase"]
  results: Foo[]
}

export const searchFoo = ({phrase}: SearchFooParams): Promise<SearchFooResponse> => {
  return Promise.resolve({
    query: phrase,
    results: [
      {id: "foo-1", name: "foo-one"}
    ],
  })
}

interface SearchBarParams {
  phrase: string
}

interface Bar {
  id: string
  name: string
}

interface SearchBarResponse {
  query: SearchBarParams["phrase"]
  results: Bar[]
}

export const searchBar = ({phrase}: SearchBarParams): Promise<SearchBarResponse> => {
  return Promise.resolve({
    query: phrase,
    results: [
      {id: "bar-2", name: "bar-two"}
    ],
  })
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
One idea is to list all possible signatures that ControllerT needs to be, instead of relying on generic support. If that's the only solution available today, I think typescript needs to improve.

This compiles, but seems painfully verbose, repetitive, and not very strict:

```js
// utils/adapters.ts
import express from 'express'
import {
  searchFoo,
  searchBar,
} from '../controllers/search'

// TODO: list 25 more examples
type ControllerT
  = typeof searchFoo
  | typeof searchBar

// TODO: list 25 more examples
type PayloadT
  = SearchFooResponse 
  | SearchBarResponse 

export const postHandler = (controller: ControllerT) => (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  controller(req.body).then((payload: PayloadT) => {
    res.status(200).json(payload)
  })
}
```

Comment: what is the definition of the `ControllerT` type? please include that code.

Comment: @szaman thanks for looking. I updated the example usage but the point is that `ControllerT` should be inferred from the usage.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `<ControllerT extends (arg: any) => Promise<any>>`?

Comment: @iz_ maybe, but `any` is not desired. All types should be defined.

Comment: How specific you want the types to be is up to you. For example, it could be as specific as `<ControllerT extends (arg: { phrase: string }) => Promise<{ query: string, results: { id: string, name: string }[] }>>` if you are sure all controllers have that structure. To me, sticking with `any` is totally fine here. Although, you may want to specify the argument type with `(arg: { phrase: string })` and check if `phrase` exists on `req.body`.

Comment: @iz_ I agree, a potential solution involves listing all the possible types again in this file, but I don't think that's the spirit of generics. The types should be inferred from the usage. Maybe its a current limitation. However, this allows me to move forward. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know much about `express` but it does seem like you should be able to make this generic in both the request body type and the response body type.  Something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZb8Dm), but I have no idea how to get the IDE to accept that `req` and `res` have the `body` and `status` properties. Is it possible for you to edit the example code to be a [mre] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE (some imports maybe?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for would be something like:

```js
import express from 'express';

type Controller<Body extends {}, Response extends {}> = (body: Body) => Promise<Response>;

export const postHandler = <
  Body extends {},
  Response extends {},
  ControllerT extends Controller<Body, Response>,
>(controller: ControllerT) => (
    (req: express.Request<{}, Body>, res: express.Response) => {
      controller(req.body).then((payload) => {
        res.status(200).json(payload);
      });
    }
  )
```

The key parts of this are first of all giving the typescript geneirc `ControllerT` a base type to extend /  go off of. In this case I defined this as:

```js
type Controller<Body extends {}, Response extends {}> = (body: Body) => Promise<Response>;
```

Which basically just says that the argument must extend an object and the response must be a Promise of an object. I think this aligns with what you're trying to achieve with controllers.

The other key part is utilising `express.Request` generic. which is defined as the following:

```js
interface e.Request<
  P extends Params = ParamsDictionary,
  ResBody = any, ReqBody = any,
  ReqQuery = QueryString.ParsedQs
>
```

i.e. it takes any url paramers that you might define like `/user/:id` or the like, the body of the request and the Query string params. I have deinfed the request as follows:

```js
   (req: express.Request<{}, Body>, res: express.Response) => {
      controller(req.body).then((payload) => {
        res.status(200).json(payload);
      });
    }
```

So I am hardcoding the params dictionary to an empty object, and am passing through the generic `Body` to the `Controller` as well as express. This allows the calling of the controller with `req.body` to not through an error as they are the same type.

The final part is ensuring that you pass through the the correct types to the `express.router` as shown:

```
const router = express.Router()
router.post<{}, SearchFooParams>('/foo', postHandler(searchFoo))
router.post<{}, SearchBarParams>('/bar', postHandler(searchBar)
```

Again this assumes that you do not need any url or query parameters. If those are also required then you can simply ass those through in the `express.Request` generic and ensure that first argument in the `Controller` generic matches it.

Comment: this is great. I'm a little annoyed the generic parameters must be specified, when I think they could be inferred. However, you've outlined a path of how to specify everything. I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: I just realized use of `postHandler` is inferred! Trying now..